# How to structure many complex conditionals on a class

Tags: go, design-patterns, conditional-statements, protocol-buffers

I have a class (as a protobuf) OrderChange, that represents when an order (imagine Amazon.com) changes:

```
message OrderChange {
  Order old_order = 1;
  Order new_order = 2;
}

message Order {
  OrderType order_type = 1;
  OrderCategory order_category = 2;
  OrderStatus order_status = 3;
  // many more fields
}

enum OrderType {
  ORDER_TYPE_RETAIL = 0;
  ORDER_TYPE_BUSINESS = 1;
}

enum OrderCategory {
  ORDER_CATEGORY_ELECTRONICS = 0;
  ORDER_CATEGORY_FOOD = 1;
  ORDER_CATEGORY_FURNITURE = 2;
  ORDER_CATEGORY_FITNESS = 3;
  ORDER_CATEGORY_HOUSEHOLD = 4;
}

enum OrderStatus {
  ORDER_STATUS_PAID = 0;
  ORDER_STATUS_SHIPPED = 1;
  ORDER_STATUS_DELIVERED = 2;
}
```

For each OrderChange object, I want to trigger some code for each conditional. For example if Order is RETAIL, FURNITURE, and PAID, I want to send a specific email.

OrderType and OrderCategory probably won't change between old_order and new_order, so my code can look at only new_order for these fields. Other fields such as OrderType will change, and my code can compare old_order and new_order to know what changed.

My problem is that Order has many fields, each with many values, so the number of conditional combinations is huge. Using only if/else or switch/case would be unmaintainable code.

So my question is, what pattern can I use to make these conditionals more maintainable?

Maybe I can break the fields into handlers - a handler for each OrderType, then each of these handlers contain a list of handlers for each OrderCategory, and continuing to nest a single field for each level until there are no more fields. My issue would be that beyond maybe the OrderType being the highest level field, there is no clear hierarchical relationship for the other fields. As in, it's not clear that OrderCategory handlers should contain OrderType handlers.

How should I design this?

Comment: Is this specific to a specific programming language?  If so please tag accordingly

Comment: Added tag for Go, but answers in any language are welcome.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because also posted on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/432403/how-to-structure-many-complex-conditionals-on-a-class

Answer (score 0):

Is the intent that there is only one action that should be triggered? Say you have actions that should run on  RETAIL + PAID and  RETAIL +  FURNITURE + PAID, these clearly can compete with each other and there would need to be a priority type system to deal with ensuring only one handled it. Something like chain of responsibility could be used, where you register the handlers in priority order. If on the other hand, you want all eligible handlers to process it, then you can simply iterate all registered change handlers and pass each the change notification and allow each to process it, which is effectively just a simple observer.

Comment: The intent is only one action should be triggered. You accurately described one of my problems. I also posted this question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/432406/120122, please take a look at the discussion on that answer if you're still interested in this question. Closing this post to dedupe.

Comment: Looks like accepted answer there is exactly what I suggested here. Good luck!